# image transition algorithms

Tags: algorithm, transition

I want to apply various transitions like wipe in, wipe out, zoom in, zoom out, split, etc. on images. Can somebody please suggest some algorithms or books that explains how to apply various transitions on images in a generalized manner?

Comment: Most of those are simple transformations and translations.  You can achieve them with simple algebra.  If you want to understand rotating, flipping animations you'll need an introductory linear algebra book.

Comment: Thanks @bdares. I have already implemented some of them but i m not 100% sure if my methods are correct. Its good to have some reference to compare my work to so I thought to ask here if there is something available then. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think [2D computer graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_computer_graphics) is probably the key-word that you're looking.  The link that I provided explains how basic transformations work, including translation, rotation, and scaling.